# Adding Amazon IP to Cpanel

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpanel

I want to add a new IP address to Cpanel. I allocated a new address on Amazon, and attached it to the server. Then from whm > IP Functions > Add a New IP Address: I typed the private IP, selected the subnet 255.255.255.255 and added it. But when I open Show or Delete Current IP Addresses, I get the error: Not Routable.

This is a screenshot of Cpanel
https://ibb.co/BgGqJD1

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the EC2 instance's public IP address. The private one can't be routed to from outside the instance. You have to make a public IP first though, as EC2 instances are not given one by default.

Comment: I use public IP already, but I want to add an additional IP to the server. The public IP can't be added directly. This is a screenshot showing the case clearly: https://ibb.co/BgGqJD1